# Set width of QuaggaJs to 100%?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a barcode scanner for a mobile web application.
Now i´d like to set the width of the "camera viewport" to fit into my div.

So in QuaggaJs you can set the size of the livestream like this:

```
Quagga.init({
    inputStream : {
        name : "Live",
        type : "LiveStream",
        target: document.querySelector('#interactive'),
        constraints: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            facing: "environment" // or user
        }
    },
```

If you "comment" the width and height the size will be bigger than my mobile screen.
So, how can i set the viewport to just fill my div?

**HTML (Bootstrap)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
  <div id="interactive" class="viewport col-md-12"></div>
  <div id="interactive" class="viewport" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set height and width whit this properties.

```
var w = window.innerWidth;

var h = window.innerHeight;
```

innerHeight and innerWidth are you screen dimensions

Comment: Thank you. I did use this and sub "w" with 30 and i got the correct width for bootstrap framework.

Comment: read: in init(), width: window.innerWidth,

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **Quagga** in **Angular** project and I handled sizing with code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="barcode_scanner"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#barcode_scanner {
    &::ng-deep video {
        width: 100%;
    }
     ::ng-deep canvas {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```